# Why Bezier Curve is not undefined at t=0 and t = 1?

Tags: limits, curves, parametric, binomial-theorem, bezier-curve

Sorry,this might be a dumb question, but I couldn't really understand it.
If we define Bezier Curves as:

$B(t) = \displaystyle\sum_{i = 0}^{n} P_i\binom{n}{i}t^i(1-t)^{n-i}$

when t and i are zero it becomes:

$B(0) = P_0\binom{n}{0}0^0(1-0)^{n}$

So here we get $0^0$, isn't this undefined?
How can $B(0)$ be equal to $P_0$

Similarly, let's assume there is a third degree Bezier Curve with points $P_0$ $P_1$ $P_2$

$B(t) = P_0t^3(1-t)^0+ 3(t)^2(1-t) + 3(t)^1(1-t)^2 + t^0(1-t)^3$

for $t = 0$, isn't this also undefined?
I think I am rather confused with binomial theorem than bezier curve